# Select column values which are present 50% more with respect to other column values in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL query(SQL Server).

I have a table which looks like this.
Table Name: Class

```
Subject Student Grade
Math      James   A
Math      John    B
Math      Eric    B
Physics   Crystal A  
Chemistry  James  C
Biology    John   A
Biology    Eric   B
```

and so on...

I want to display table with all columns but where the occurrence of student names are found 50 percent or higher for the Subject column

So for example if student name - 'James' occurs for 2 out 4 subjects then his name should be displayed and should exclude other who fall under 50% criteria.

Thanks

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6167855

Comment: It's SQL server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Having...

```
select Student
from Class
group by Student
having count(Student) >= (select count(distinct [Subject]) from Class) / 2.0
```

Or if you like variables...

```
declare @numOfSubjects int = (select count(distinct [Subject]) from Class)

select Student
from Class
group by Student
having count(Student) >= @numOfSubjects / 2.0
```

To bring back all columns you can wrap it in a CTE

```
with cte as(
    select Student
    from Class
    group by Student
    having count(Student) >= (select count(distinct [Subject]) from Class)) / 2.0)

select 
    c.*
from Class c
inner join cte on cte.Student = c.Student
```

Comment: You are missing the 50% term though :-)

Comment: HA! Good catch @GiorgosAltanis

Comment: And I think I have another one :-) Isn't integer division a bit dangerous here?

Comment: he said that needs all columns no just Student

Comment: I didn't think it'd throw off since the division would always be .0 or .5 but fair point

Comment: @user3613720 yes, i fixed that with the division as hilighted by Giorgos who was on point

Comment: No more objections from me, upvoting!

Answer (score 1):

Just to get all the columns ...

```
select *
from Class
where Student in (select Student
                    from Class
                   group by Student
                  having count(Student) >= (select count(distinct [Subject]) from Class) / 2.0)
```